# Connecting to Redshift from DBeaver using ssh and JDBC only working from Mac

Tags: windows, jdbc, ssh, amazon-redshift, dbeaver

I am trying to provision GUI client access to an AWS Redshift Database via an EC2 ssh bastion. For some reason I am able to get this working on Mac but not on Windows.

Initially I was trying to use [SQLWorkbench/J](https://www.sql-workbench.eu/) which was very tricky to configure and seems to have trouble reading ssh private keys. In the end I gave up using its native ssh tunneling feature and configured a tunnel separately using sshuttle. This works fine but of course sshuttle is only available for nix based systems and of course some people on my team have to use windows....

I have then come across [DBeaver](https://dbeaver.io/) which seems a lot more polished and was much quicker and easier to set up. I am able to use the native ssh features with SSHJ to tunnel via my bastion using ssh key authentication from my mac without difficulty. Unfortunately, the exact same settings (ssh key; DBeaver 22.1.0) on a windows 10 client from the same IP address don't work - I get timeouts for 'test tunnel configuration'. I am able to connect to the bastion using 'native' OpenSSH from the windows client.

What am I missing? DBeaver is permitted in the Windows defender firewall and the configuration should otherwise be similar. Mac install is via Brew, Windows via Chocolatey

Answer (score 0):

After I circumvented the issue with a port forward I discovered that it was caused by an apparently 'stale' line in .ssh/known-hosts referring to my bastion.I didn't have any issue with SSH in my terminal but on deleting this line I was able to connect.

Poor error handling from DBeaver